# How to change combobox values from csv in real time in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a csv file Cars.csv. It contains a list of cars: Ferrari, Lamborghini, Mercedes...
With my script if I change Ferrari with AlfaRomeo in csv, combobox doesn't update in the opened tkinter app.
My question is how I can create a function to read csv values in combobox in real time.

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1250x750")
root.resizable(False, False)



with open('Cars.csv') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
     list_cars = list(csv_reader)

def car_changed(event):
    global car_selected
    car_selected = car_cb.get()
   
    
selected_car = tk.StringVar()

car_cb = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=selected_car, width=15, font=("Bold",15))
car_cb['values'] = list_cars
car_cb['state'] = 'readonly'  # normal
car_cb.place(x=185,y=90)

car_cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', car_changed)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

## File watcher

You can use a library like [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) to get notified when the file changes.

## Polling

You can have a loop running forever. In this loop, you read the file and look for changes. If there was a change you update your gui.
This loop must run in a separate thread and you should add a `sleep` after each iteration.

An improvement may be to only read the last edit date and check if it updated.

Note: In both cases you need to save the file before it is updated.

## Manual

Not automatic but the simplest option ist to add an button, that reloads the data.

## Other solution

I don't know your application, but you may want to use other options than editing a csv file.

## Notes

All these options only work, after the file is saved.
To make it really real time you would need an editor integration.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I'm searching a solution after the csv file is saved not real time. I exclude a button because I have many comboboxes in my application. I watch polling or file watcher. Thanks, James